# Attempting to restart Celery processes via Supervisor results in error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, celery, supervisord, celeryd

I am running supervisor/celery on an amazon aws server. Attempting to deploy a new application version eventually fails because the celery processes are not started. I have taken a look at the supervisord.conf file to ensure that the programs are included, which they are. At the end of the supervisord.conf file I have the following include:

```
[include]
files=celeryd.conf
files=flower.conf
```

I try to restart celery with

```
sudo /usr/local/bin/supervisorctl -c /opt/python/etc/supervisord.conf restart celeryd-default celeryd-slowtasks
```

celeryd-defualt and celeryd-slowtaks being the names of the programs listed in celeryd.conf. I get the following error:

```
celeryd-default: ERROR (no such process)
celeryd-slowtasks: ERROR (no such process)
celeryd-default: ERROR (no such process)
celeryd-slowtasks: ERROR (no such process)
```

If I run

```
sudo /usr/local/bin/supervisorctl -c /opt/python/etc/supervisord.conf restart all
```

I get

```
flower: stopped
httpd: stopped
httpd: started
flower: started
```

without any mention of celery. Any idea how to start figuring this issue out?

Answer (score 0):

Check /opt/python/etc/supervisord.conf, you are probably including a folder that you don't expect to be included.

Also ensure that the instance of supervisor that is running is actually using the config file you ex

Comment: There are no folders that I'm not expecting in my supervisord.conf file. How can I check that the supervisor instance is actually using my config file?

Comment: You can do a ps -ef and check for the whole command line, also you can go to /proc/{pid}/fd (where pid is the process id of supervisor) and check there which config file it is opening,.